# Natvis C++/WinRT: Exception in cppwinrt_visualizer::EvaluateVisualizedExpression

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winui-3, c++-winrt, windows-app-sdk

The code below results in this exception even with an empty XML(only the page tag):

```
Natvis C++/WinRT: Exception in cppwinrt_visualizer::EvaluateVisualizedExpression
Natvis C++/WinRT: Exception in cppwinrt_visualizer::EvaluateVisualizedExpression
Natvis C++/WinRT: Exception in cppwinrt_visualizer::EvaluateVisualizedExpression
Natvis C++/WinRT: Exception in cppwinrt_visualizer::EvaluateVisualizedExpression
```

The error happens on this line `rootFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<ProjectNamespace::FirstPage>(), box_value(e.Arguments()));`

```
void App::OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs const& e)
{
    window = make<MainWindow>();

    Frame rootFrame = Frame();
    rootFrame.NavigationFailed({this, &App::OnNavigationFailed});
    rootFrame.Navigate(xaml_typename<ProjectNamespace::FirstPage>(),
                       box_value(e.Arguments()));

    window.Content(rootFrame);
    window.Activate();
}
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: There is no issue with the code. The error is caused by the debugger visualizer that's part of C++/WinRT. It is invoked by the debugger whenever it needs to display a value, such as in a Watch window or a tooltip. The visualizer hasn't seen much love in a long time, and the observed issue has been there for more than four years. It is down to a fix that, when the visualizer cannot produce a display value, stops trying. Previously, it was trying too hard, and in doing so, frequently crashed the IDE.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. As @IInspectable said, there is no issue with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagnostic message doesn't indicate a problem with the *code*. It originates in C++/WinRT's [debug visualizer](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/natvis) implementation attempting to supply human-readable insights to the debugger. [This](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/23c4ced66ac1672a2326eec3e6b1c24f42353c3c/natvis/cppwinrt_visualizer.cpp#L194-L250) is the faulting function:

```cpp
HRESULT cppwinrt_visualizer::EvaluateVisualizedExpression(...)
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // If something goes wrong, just fail to display object/property.  Don't take down VS.
        NatvisDiagnostic(pVisualizedExpression, 
            L"Exception in cppwinrt_visualizer::EvaluateVisualizedExpression", NatvisDiagnosticLevel::Error, to_hresult());
        return E_FAIL;
    }
}
```

The comment suggests this is a known issue but hasn't been fully fixed. Damage is contained, and instead of crashing the debugger, this function doesn't visualize an object or property if it finds that it can't, for any number of reasons.

#### Repro

This is enough information to construct a repro:

0. Prepare a Visual Studio instance for WinUI 3 development with C++/WinRT.
1. Create a new *"Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)"* project.
2. Open **Tools** → **Options...**, navigate to **Debugging** → **Output Window**, and set the *"Natvis diagnostic messages (C++ only)"* verbosity to *"Error"*.
3. Set a breakpoint in `App::OnLaunched()` on this line:

   ```cpp
    window = make<MainWindow>();
   ```
4. Select **Debug** → **Start Debugging**.
5. When the breakpoint is hit open **Debug** → **Windows** → **Autos**.
6. Step over this line (**Debug** → **Step Over**).

At this point, the *"Debug"* output pane will show several errors like the following:

```
Natvis C++/WinRT: Exception in cppwinrt_visualizer::EvaluateVisualizedExpression
```

#### Solution

Since the issue is inside the C++/WinRT debug visualizer implementation, there's nothing we can do to fix it. It would need to be addressed by one of the Windows App SDK, MSBuild, or C++/WinRT teams. Given past experience with problems where XAML and C++/WinRT meet, I'm reluctant to even file an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues).

Users are left with two options:

- Ignore output messages that start with `Natvis C++/WinRT:`.
- Have Visual Studio suppress *"Natvis diagnostic message"* altogether by setting the verbosity level to *"Off"*.